# How to pass variable to targets in the options for renderDataTable (shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

The following can disable filter for column 1 and column 3 in the rendered data table:

```
output$datatbl <- DT::renderDataTable(
dt$df, rownames = FALSE,
filter = 'top',
options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, 
               columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(1,3), searchable = FALSE))))
```

However, I have different datasets uploaded to my app, so the column to be disabled for search will be different. I need to pass variable to update the value for `targets` in the `options`. I tried the following (the `expr` inside `eval(substitute()` is to catch the indices of the columns which are found in a reactive value list dt$datecolchoices):

```
output$datatbl <- DT::renderDataTable(
dt$df, rownames = FALSE,
filter = 'top',
options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, 
               columnDefs = list(list(targets = eval(substitute(which(names(dt$df) %in% dt$datecolchoices))), searchable = FALSE))))
```

However, it seems the above doesn't pass the value of the var to `targets` as I expected as the columns are not disabled for filter. Is there anything wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: I think it's because `eval(substitute())` not called in a function environment. I'd like to know how to embed a function here to change the value of `targets` in options. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine the column names by position beforehand and pass them into the targets argument like this:

```
output$datatbl <- DT::renderDataTable({

  disable_search_targets <- which(colnames(iris) %in% c('Petal.Length', 'Species'))

  datatable(iris, 
            options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, 
                           columnDefs = list(list(targets = disable_search_targets, 
                                                  searchable  = FALSE))))
})
```